# About sets using arrays and bit vectors

Tags: c, math, data-structures, set

I am reading about Array and Bit-Vector sets at following location.

http://www.brpreiss.com/books/opus4/html/page390.html

> In this section we consider finite sets over a finite universe.
>   Specifically, the universe we consider is {0,1,..., N-1}, the set of
>   integers in the range from zero to N-1, for some fixed and relatively
>   small value of N.
>
> Let U= 0,1,..., N-1}  be the universe. Every set which we wish to
>   represent is a subset of U. The set of all subsets of U is called the
>   power set  of U and is written 2 ^ U (i.e., 2 to power of U) . Thus,
>   the sets which we wish to represent are the elements of 2 ^ U. The
>   number of elements in the set U, written |U|, is N. Similarly, |2^U| =
>   2^|U|=2^N.  This observation should be obvious: For each element of
>   the universal set U there are only two possibilities: Either it is, or
>   it is not, a member of the given set.
>
> This suggests a relatively straightforward representation of the
>   elements of 2^U--an array of Boolean values, one for each element of
>   the universal set. By using array subscripts in U, we can represent
>   the set implicitly. I.e., i is a member of the set if the i th  array
>   element is true.

My questions on above text are

1. What author mean by statement " The set of all subsets of U is called the power set  of U and is written 2 ^ U (i.e., 2 to power of U)? For example if we  have U= {0,1,2} then we have 2^3 = 8 is set of all sub sets but we are having more than 8 for example {empty set}, {0}, {1}, {2}, {0,1}, {0,2}, {0,3}, {1,2}, and {1,2,3} which is 9. Please correct me if I am wrong?
2. How author and why came up with power of 2 rather than with any other number like 3 etc?

Please clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer @haccks gave for the first question is correct, but I think understanding the second question is actually more important because it shows exactly what a bit array really is.

You represent your set `{0,1,2}` as a bit array like so:

```
2 1 0  <-- set members
0 0 0  <-- bit array value (present/not present)
```

(I've ordered the set backwards for reasons that will become apparent in a moment.)
The bit array `[0,0,0]` represents the empty set. None of the set members are present. The subset `{1,2}` is represented as:

```
2 1 0  <-- set members
1 1 0  <-- bit array value
```

Each set member can either be present, or not present; zero or one. Two possibilities for each member means we have `2*2*2=2^3` subsets of a set with 3 elements. So this is where the author comes up with `2` and not some other number.

You should now be able to see that the bit array is nothing more than a binary number with `|U|` bits. In fact, one way you generate the power set is to count in binary from `0` to `(2^|U|)-1`:

```
0  000  {}
1  001  {0}
2  010  {1}
3  011  {0,1}
4  100  {2}
5  101  {0,2}
6  110  {1,2}
7  111  {0,1,2}
```

It should also now be apparent that I've ordered the set backwards so that the first element lines up with the LSB of the binary number corresponding to the bit array. You can order it the other way, but it seems a bit more logical for `bit 0` to correspond to `U[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

The power set of `U= {0,1,2}` will contain

```
{empty set}
{0}
{1}
{2}
{0,1}
{0,2}
{1,2}
{0,1,2}
```

Which equals to 2<sup>|U|</sup>.

I wonder how did you came to subsets `{0,3}` and `{1,2,3}` ?